# How do I allocate memory for a textstring from the terminal?

Tags: c, memory-management

So I have a struct where I have my char array, it looks like this,

```
typedef struct data_{
  char * path;
} data;
```

I want to be able to type a huge string in the terminal and save the string in this array, what I have tried now is this,

```
data * data_ptr = malloc(sizeof(data));

data_ptr->path = malloc(sizeof(argv[i]) + 1); /*+ 1 to allocate an extra bit for I/O*/
strcpy(data->path, argv[i]);
```

and before I quit the program I free the memory. But I get Segmentation fault for some reason. I have allocated memory on two other places in my code and they seem to work just fine.. I'm kind of new to Valgrind and trying to decode what it is trying to tell me that the problem is but it yells too much for me too comprehend.

```
==3117== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3117== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3117== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3117== Command: ./***
==3117== 
==3117== Syscall param open(filename) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==3117==    at 0x4F30460: __open_nocancel (syscall-template.S:84)
==3117==    by 0x4EB3ACD: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:221)
==3117==    by 0x4EB3D34: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:328)
==3117==    by 0x4EA7D33: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:86)
==3117==    by 0x400AF7: search_file (in /home/***)
==3117==    by 0x400BE5: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3117==    at 0x400B8C: main (in /home/***)
==3117== 
File does not exist.
==3117== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3117==    at 0x4C2EDA1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3117==    by 0x400BF1: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3117==    at 0x400B8C: main (in /home/***)
==3117== 
==3117== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3117==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3117==    by 0x400BF1: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Address 0x400770 is in the Text segment of /home/***
==3117==    at 0x400770: _start (in /home/***)
==3117== 
==3117== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3117==    at 0x4C2EDA1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3117==    by 0x400BFD: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3117==    at 0x400B8C: main (in /home/***)
==3117== 
==3117== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3117==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3117==    by 0x400BFD: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Address 0xffefffeb0 is on thread 1's stack
==3117== 
==3117== 
==3117== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3117==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==3117==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 4 frees, 1,600 bytes allocated
==3117== 
==3117== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3117==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3117==    by 0x400882: parse (in /home/***)
==3117==    by 0x400BC6: main (in /home/***)
==3117== 
==3117== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3117==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==3117==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3117==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3117==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3117==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3117== 
==3117== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3117== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is anyone able to see what I may be doing wrong? My take on Valgrinds output is that I try to reach memory that I do not have access to, or that I am messing with the stack in some strange way. But I do not know to be honest.

Comment: Maybe you rathe need this: `typedef struct data_{ char path[YOUR_MAX_PATH_LENGTH]; } data;`. In your example `path` is not an array but a pointer.

Comment: ... and thiks looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: It is not meant to be a XY Problem, I'm just trying to allocate the memory and tell you how I have done it, I can rephrase the question to my full extent if you think it would be easier to find a good solution to the problem.

Comment: I can understand that you have censored the paths in the Valgrind output a little, but maybe you censored it to much? If you have a debug-build (build with the `-g` flag and don't strip debugging symbols) then Valgrind should be able to tell you the lines where the problems are. Have you looked at those lines?

Comment: All I censored was the path to my file. If you replace *** with "/home/scooby_doo/Documents/C/Exercise/Memory_Allocation/memory" you get the full picture of the output.

Comment: I called valgrind like this: valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./memory , and compiled it like this: gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Iparser -Isearcher -I memory.c -o memory

Comment: In the `gcc` command line, add the `-g` option to include debug information (so Valgrind will be able to give you more accurate information).

Comment: Yes I did that after you told so and found a quite interesting output also, ==3584== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--3584--     old: 0x0401cdc0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x3809e181 ???
--3584--     new: 0x0401cdc0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c31020 strlen

Comment: Seems like it is trying to use the same peace of memory I allocated before this if I understand it correct, also included the -v flag this time in valgrind.

Comment: When you compile with -g, use gdb to run the program "gdb ./memory" and stop after the strcpy. At that point, does data_ptr->path contain /home/scooby_doo/Documents/C/Exercise/Memory_Allocation/mem‌​ory?

Comment: Also, from your comment, it looks like you're trying to open the executable file memory. Is that correct? Or are you trying to do something like get the current running directory from the path of the executable?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
data_ptr->path = malloc(sizeof(argv[i]) + 1)
```

is wrong, you can't use `sizeof` to get the length of a string at runtime like that. You must use `strlen()`:

```
data_ptr->path = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
```

If you have it, you can use `strdup()` to do both the allocation and the copying. Saves you from having to remember that `+ 1`.

Comment: It did not seem to help, it still compiles but the segmentation fault remain and valgrind still yells at me. I just have to go through the code one more time. Will soon be back. EDIT: It must have been one peace of why it does not work but I must have done something else wrong also

Comment: It really does "help", since what you had before was wrong and would give you undefined behavior when storing more than four characters.

Comment: I agree, but it still does not work and it makes me think that I may have been doing something wrong somewhere else also.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[i]` is a *pointer* to a string, but not the string itself. Therefore when you do `sizeof(argv[i])` you only get the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

So when you do `malloc(sizeof(argv[i]) + 1)` you will only allocate `5` or `9` bytes (depending on the pointers size, typically 4 bytes for 32-bit systems and 8 bytes for 64-bit systems).

You need to use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use strlen(argv[i]) rather than sizeof

```
data * data_ptr = malloc(sizeof(data));

data_ptr->path = malloc(strlen(argv[i])); 
strcpy(data->path, argv[i]);
```

I hope that the value of i is within the range 0 to argc..

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't use `sizeof`, you should use `strlen` when doing the `malloc`.

But, valgrind is telling you what's wrong, you're trying to open a file that doesn't exist.

```
==3117== Syscall param open(filename) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==3117==    at 0x4F30460: __open_nocancel (syscall-template.S:84)
==3117==    by 0x4EB3ACD: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:221)
==3117==    by 0x4EB3D34: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:328)
==3117==    by 0x4EA7D33: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:86)
==3117==    by 0x400AF7: search_file (in /home/***)
==3117==    by 0x400BE5: main (in /home/***)
==3117==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3117==    at 0x400B8C: main (in /home/***)
==3117== 
File does not exist.
```

So, perhaps you're attempting to open a file that's bogus (i.e. the value of `filename` is bogus or it's just garbage data)? Or, you're passing bogus data to `fopen`? What is the path you're passing to `fopen`?

Comment: The file exist, Im shure of it. Before I started to do all the memory code I copied all my old code so if nothing would work I could easy go back. And if I use the old code, it is working. If use the new, it is not working and I call it the same and to the same filé.

Comment: So, what are contents of the string you're passing to fopen? You can use a printf to see it on the terminal, or step through using gdb to see what it contains.